# Менять размер векторного ресурса

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Возможно ли программно менять размер vector drawable до того как она будет отрендерена?

Хочу чтобы на карте была возможность менять размер иконок маркеров(без пиксилизации)..

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="20dp"
    android:height="20dp">....</vector >
```

Comment: если для ImageView установить vectorDrawable то он будет автоматически масштабироваться в зависимости от размера ImageView

Comment: Нет не для ImageView. И вроде он не масштабируется автоматом(без пиксилизации) в ImageView, вроде только если scaleType XY указать..

Comment: я тестировал по умолчанию все работает

Comment: Можешь получить из вектора Bitmap и делать с ним все что тебе угодно